# Podio API - PHP - Create Item - Item not found error

Tags: php, podio

We have service ticket app and client app. The service ticket app have a look up field to client app.

We post service tickets from external applications through PHP API. The integration working fine for the last two years.

We recently found that the service ticket items are not created for a specific client only.

In the PHP script, we search the client app, get the id and create the item in service ticket app. It works perfectly for other clients.

The client exists in the clients app and we are able to get the item ID also.

But we get insert error in the item creation.

The error is :

> not_found No item with id 59745524 could be found.

Comment: Which authentication are you using for getting items from Client app?

Comment: I use this code to authenticate.    Podio::authenticate_with_app($clappid, $clapptoken);
This error raised for a specific client only.

Comment: so, where `59745524` is coming from?

Comment: I get this id by searching the clients app. But while inserting with the same id, it throws error.